# Factorization of polynomials in Galois Field 2

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

I want to know what is the general rule for factorization of the generator polynomial which is based on Galois Field, GF2?

Fact is, a generator of degree m must divide `1+x^n` where remainder is zero. for example `1+x^7` ca be written as

```
(1+x+x3)(1+x2+x3)(1+x)
```

So either `1+x+x3` or `1+x2+x3` can be used.

What is the systematic rule for decomposing `1+x7`?

Comment: Sounds like this is for using cyclic codes. In other words, the polynomial you want to factor will always be of the form $x^n+1$. Instead of the factors you can also use the idempotents of the cyclic code. Those are very straightforward to find. See [a recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3616801/11619). Actually Berlekamp's algorithm that Dietrich refers to begins by finding the idempotents modulo the polynomial to be factored. In general it is a bit more complicated, but for polynomials of this special form idempotents correspond to cyclotomic cosets.

Comment: The step from idempotents to factors is a bit more complicated, but manageable. To get the minimal cyclic codes you want the so called orthogonal idempotents. I don't remember all the details, and it's too late an hour for me to think it through - may be tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have better feeling with the second answer in the link you posted. So, it seems that `1+xn` is written as `p.q.r` where `p=1+x`. But I don't understand the rest. So, `1+x7` will be `(1+x)(1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6)`. I don't understand the rest then...

Comment: That's fine. Different answers bring up different points of view. I brought it up because in coding theory using the idempotents is one way of looking at. At least among math people - telcomm engineers less so. But really, idempotents are in a sense at the heart of Berlekamp. Every time you find a non-trivial polynomial $e(x)$ such that $e(x)^2\equiv e(x)\pmod {x^n+1}$ you can find a non-trivial factor of $x^m+1$ by calculating $\gcd(e(x), x^m+1)$. And that is trivial with the extended Euclid's algorithm,

Answer (score 2):

A systematic way is to apply the [Berlekamp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm). It gives
$$
x^7+1=(x^3 + x^2 + 1)(x^3 + x + 1)(x + 1),
$$
as you said. Or
$$
x^{11}+1=(x^{10} + x^9 + x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)(x + 1)
$$

Comment: I read that but I can not apply that for the example. Actually I don't know how to initialize that and how to find the GCDs.