# Why does a polynomial over a composite modulus have more than $d$ roots, but over a prime modulus it has at most $d$ roots?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Is it true that when considering a degree $d$ polynomial $p(x)$ in a composite modulus $q$, it has more than $d$ roots (i.e., more than $d$ solutions to $p(x) \equiv 0 \pmod q$), and that when we consider $p(x)$ in a prime modulus $p$, it still satisfies the property of polynomials that it will have at most $d$ roots? If so, why? If not, is it only the case that with a composite modulus, we will sometimes but not always get more than $d$ roots?

I am asking because I have seen that $x^3 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$ has more than $3$ roots, but whenever I work over a prime it seems to always have at most $d$ roots, which has made me wonder what the relationship is between the modulus and how many roots there are, and most importantly why this relationship is the case.

Comment: As proved in the dupes, it is true in domains by iterating the factor theorem, and there are simple counterexamples in nondomains, e.g. if $\,ab=0, a,b\neq 0\,$ then $\,ax\,$ has at least $2$ roots $\,b,0;\,$ and $\,(x-a)(x-b)\,$ has at least $\,4\,$ roots $\,a,b,0,a+b\, $ if $\,a\neq  b.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I understand how the iterating factor theorem shows that $p(x)$ has at most $d$ roots if we aren't doing modular arithmetic and just talking about polynomials in general. However, I am not seeing why this line of reasoning still holds when working modulo a prime, and why this line of reasoning fails when working modulo a composite. Why is it the case that $\ r\ne r_i\,\Rightarrow\, f(r)= c(r\!-\!r_1)\cdots (r\!-\!r_n) \ne 0\,$ when we are working modulo a prime, but not necessarily when working modulo a composite? (I see why it works in general). thanks

Comment: The proof by iterating the Factor Theorem needs all root differences to be *cancellable*, which may fail when there are zero-divisors - see the proof of the Bifactor Theorem in the first dupe.   Note that generally for composite moduli we can count the number of roots using CRT (which combines *multiplicatively* - clarifying how the count can exceed the degree when the modulus has more than one prime factor, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/902051/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3250900/242)). $\ \ $

Comment: Note that it's not true that there must be more roots than the degree for composite  moduli, e.g.  $x(x-1)$ has only roots $\,x=0,1\,$ for prime power moduli $p^n$ cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/902051/242).

Comment: To gain insight I recommend that you trace the proof of the BiFactor Theorem for the roots $\,x=1,3\,$ of $\,x^2-1\,$ in $\Bbb Z_8$ to see how it breaks down (by not being able to cancel an even mod $8).\ \ $